# Why am I getting this error: Not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, binary-search

I have this C++ code that contains the following errors: 
1. `readBinaryFile` was not declared in this scope
2. `ret` was not declared in this scope
3. `recursiveBinarySearch` was not declared in this scope.

Can someone please help me understand why these errors are coming up?

Thank you in advance.

BinarySearch.h

```
    #ifndef BINARYSEARCH_H
    #define BINARYSEARCH_H

    using namespace std;

    class BinarySearch
    {

       public:
           char readBinaryFile(char *fileName);
           int recursiveBinarySearch(int start_index, int end_index, int        targetValue);
    };

    #endif
```

BinarySearch.cpp

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;

    //vector to dynamically store large number of values...
    vector<unsigned int> ret; 

    //variable to count the number of comparisions...  
    int n=0;  
    //method to read file....  
    void readBinaryFile(char* fileName)
    {
        ifstream read(fileName);
        unsigned int current;
        if(read!=NULL)
        while (read>>current) {
            ret.push_back(current);
        }

    }

    //recursive binary search method

    void recursiveBinarySearch(int start_index, int end_index, int targetValue)
    {

       int mid = (start_index+end_index)/2;

       if(start_index>end_index)
       {
          cout<<n<<":-"<<endl;
           return ;  
       }

       if(ret.at(mid)==targetValue)
       {
          n++;
           cout<<n<<":"<<mid<<endl;
           return ;  
       }
       else if(ret.at(mid)<targetValue)
       {
           n=n+2;//upto here two comparisions have been made..so adding two
           start_index=mid+1;
           return recursiveBinarySearch(start_index,end_index,targetValue) ;
       }
       else
       {
           n=n+2;
           end_index=mid-1;
           return recursiveBinarySearch(start_index,end_index,targetValue) ;
       }
    }
```

BinarySearch_test.cpp

```
    #include "BinarySearch.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

       char a[] ="dataarray.bin";
       //assuming that all integers in file are already in sorted order
       readBinaryFile(a);

       int targetValue;
       cout<<"Enter a Value to search:";
       cin>>targetValue;

       recursiveBinarySearch(0,ret.size()-1,targetValue) ;


       return 0;

    }
```

Comment: binarySearch.cpp doesn't include the .h file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @AndyG I did not include that on the code here by accident but the original code has it.

Comment: @H.choi: Don't forget to scope your functions when you define them later. How else will the compiler know that `recursiveBinarySearch` is supposed to be for a `BinarySearch` object? Also, you need to actually create an instance of the class before you can use its functions. `BinarySearch::readBinaryFile` Perhaps you are more used to Java or its ilk, but those functions can be free-floating; they don't need to be part of a class.

Answer (score 0):

In your .cpp file you miss the class name to define your functions for `BinarySearch::`

```
void BinarySearch::readBinaryFile(char* fileName)
{
   //code here
}
```

and as mentioned above, since the methods are not static you will need an object to call them.

```
BinarySearch x;
x.readBinary(...);
```

Comment: maybe I should have read all the comments -- the answer was already given. Is there a reason why most people answer by comments instead of "real" answers, so that the question can also be marked as answered!?